# Why aren't radicands formed this way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

In a standard College Algebra textbook, I encountered the claim that

> In many situation, radicands are never formed by raising negative quantities to even powers

Literally the very first exercise problem for the section is then to simplify $\sqrt{(-21)^2}$, which doesn't inspire confidence in the claim.  To be clear, I understand that I can't "simplify" this to $-21^{2/2}$ because I know $\sqrt{-21}$ isn't a real number.  So why should I start making assumptions when facing expressions like $\sqrt{x^2}$?

How is this claim justified?  In what types of situations can I rely on this assumption?

EDIT Perhaps I can be clearer about what I don't understand.

The textbook has given these equalities as tools for simplification when we know that $\sqrt[n]{a}$ exists:

> $\sqrt[n]{a^m} = (\sqrt[n]{a})^m = a^{m/n}$

Now, clearly this can't be used to say $\sqrt{-21^2} = -21^{2/2}$, because $\sqrt{-21}$ does not exist (as a real number).  So $\sqrt[n]{a^m} = a^{m/n}$ can be useful as a tool for simplification, but it only holds true when making the assumption that radicands aren't being formed by raising negative quantities to even powers.

What I don't understand is why the textbook makes the claim that **in most situations radicands are never** formed this way.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(-21)^2=21^2$, and since $21\geqslant0$, $\sqrt{(-21)^2}=\sqrt{21^2}=21$. No need for assumptions here.

More generally, if $x\in\Bbb R$, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, since $x^2=|x|^2$ and $|x|\geqslant0$.

Comment: $\sqrt[n]{a^m} = (\sqrt[n]{a})^m = a^{m/n}$ is the equality where the assumption needs to be made of no negative quantities raised to even powers.  My question is why should it be the case that we can make that assumption when simplifying radicals with variables?

Comment: But we *don't* make that assumption. As I wrote, $\sqrt{x^2}$ is $|x|$, not $x$.

Comment: And for dealing with something like $\sqrt[3]{x^{12}}$?  Perhaps I chose poorly in selecting $\sqrt{x^2}$ as my example.  

In any case, the textbook takes the time to point out the assumption, and a Google search for the claim shows that hundreds of other sites say to make the same assumption when simplifying expressions.  There's no question about whether it's a common assumption, just why it's valid "in many situations" as my textbook claims.

Comment: That's easy: $\sqrt[3]{x^{12}}=\sqrt[3]{(x^4)^3}=x^4$. More generally, you always have $\sqrt[3]{\alpha^3}=\alpha$.

Comment: I think you've eloquently addressed a question I'm not trying to ask, which comes from a poorly phrased question.  I've added some edits to my question